# force user to explicitly declare variables

Tags: dart

Does Dart have a declaration that will flag variables if they have not been declared?

Eg: VBA has `Option Explicit`statement in the code. Is there anything similar in Dart?

Comment: Do you mean Dart? Don't you have to declare a variable to use it already?

Comment: Yes, Dart on flutter

Comment: If you're using optional parameters you could use the annotation @required to tell them that parameter needs to be declared

Answer (score 1):

Dart does not allow you to refer to variables that have not been declared. It is as if "Option Explict" is the default, and there is no way to opt out.

If you write an identifier expression, like `x`, Dart first checks if there is a declaration named `x` in the current lexical scope. If not, and it's an instance member, it checks if `x` is a declared member of the type of `this`. If not, it's a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the pedantic analyser. It forces you to declare types and improves the maintainability of you code.

https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic